# <br /><b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable:

Tags: php, pdo, crud

Newbie here .. im trying to program an inventory system wherein when i try to update some data an undefined variable occurred in each text boxes .. i hope you will help me ...... here's my code....

**edit.php**

```
<tr>
    <td>WS Number</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='wsnum' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $inv_ws; ?>" required></td>
</tr>
```

and i have a class wherein the update, edit and delete function are in one php file

```
public function update($inv_ws,$inv_flr,$inv_prod,$inv_os)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE activated_ws SET WS_Num=:wsnum, 
                                                   Floor=:flr, 
                                                   Prod_Key=:prd, 
                                                   OS_Type=:os
                                                WHERE WS_Num=:wsnum ");

        $stmt->bindparam(":wsnum",$inv_ws);
        $stmt->bindparam(":flr",$inv_flr);
        $stmt->bindparam(":prd",$inv_prod);
        $stmt->bindparam(":os",$inv_os);
        $stmt->execute();

        return true;    
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();  
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your variable is still undefined

Comment: Where are you defining the `$inv_ws` that you are using on the input?

Comment: @JorgeCampos the $inv_ws was used to echo the specific data i want to update on the table i have ..